# Calendar Events to Sheet is Duplicating - remove duplicates not working

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, duplicates, google-calendar-api, google-sheets-api

See code below:  It's set to update on calendar event.
But events are still duplicating onto the sheet.
Can you take a look and see where I went wrong?

get only new created events - is there a way to getevents by created date (now)?

```
   } 

   var events = calendar.getEvents(start, end); 
   var eventDetails = []; 


  var eventarray = new Array();
for(var i = 0; i<events.length; i++){ 
    eventDetails.push([events[i].getLocation(), events[i].getTitle(), events[i].getDescription(), events[i].getStartTime()]); 
 
    }
    var startRow =  sheet.getLastRow();
    var startCol = 2; 
    for(var j = 0; j<eventDetails.length; j++){ 
    var tempRange = sheet.getRange(startRow+j,startCol, 1, 4); 
    var eventArray = new Array(eventDetails[j]); 
    tempRange.setValues(eventArray); 
  } 
  //Here lies the problem code//
   for(i in eventDetails){
    var row = eventDetails[i];
    var duplicate = false;
    for(j in eventArray){

      if(row.slice(0,2).join() == eventArray[j].slice(0,2).join()){
        duplicate = true;
      }
    }
    }
    if(!duplicate){
      eventArray.push(row);
      {
  return eventArray;
    ss.sort(2, true);
  }
}
}
```

Comment: I think you're using a very convoluted code for a quite easy task. Could you please clarify what you want to accomplish? You want to append newly created events, which are still not in the sheet (and of course, ignore the ones already there)? Could you provide a copy of the spreadsheet you are working on, free of sensitive information?

Comment: @lamblichus I'm a noob to scripts and this is a very important project.  The code seems convoluted to me too. I want to put only new events that are added from a calendar into a sheet. Here's a copy [link] (https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1biP7UYGQjNCPvfC4Fiz9gBb4aCRCWdit9Pkp7WQjV08/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: I still don't understand your predicament. So, you are retrieving some events from calendar (those between certain dates). And you want to write those events to your sheet. But here comes the questions: what do you mean by `duplicates`? Events that were previously copied to the sheet, so you don't want to copy them again?

Comment: What's the purpose of `row.slice(0,2).join() == eventArray[j].slice(0,2).join()` in finding these duplicates? Both `row` and `eventArray` come from `eventDetails`, so I don't understand why are you comparing that (you are not checking events that were previously added to the sheet). And why `slice(0,2)`? Do you only need to check `location` and `title` in order to see which ones are duplicates? I have the feeling your issue can be easily solved, but first it would be necessary to understand what exactly you want to accomplish.

Comment: I want to write the events from a calendar to a sheet. When new events are added to the calendar, I want the sheet to write only the new events and not all of the events all over again to the sheet.  I tried this and it's not working either:  var row = eventDetails[i]
      var duplicate = false;
      for(j in eventArray){
        if (row == eventArray[j]){
          duplicate = true;
        }
                           }
      if (!duplicate){
        eventArray.push(row);}

Comment: Alright, what's the criteria to know which events are duplicate? Same `location`, `title`, `description` and `start time`?

Comment: Also, what's the range of the current events (already in the sheet before executing the script)? `startRow: 9`, `startColumn: B`? And also, the 4 event fields that you want to write to the sheet are also `location`, `title`, `description` and `start time`, right?

Comment: Yes! Thanks for helping!  criteria is {location, title, description].  [startRow = sheet.getLastRow() + 1; startColumn: 2]

Comment: Thank you! Those coordinates are where you want to write the new events, but I'm asking for the list of events **already in the sheet** before executing the script (the old events, let's say). I guess that would probably be row 8. But I'm not sure. About the startColumn, please keep in mind that column indexes are 1-based, so column 2 refers to `B`, not to `C`. I hope that's clear.

Comment: Yes, current events are starting in row 8 and down (about 500 events).  Column 2 is B, yes, the column to start writing the events to. @lamblichus

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Issue:

- You have a sheet with data from a list Calendar events.
- You want a script to retrieve and write any new events, ignoring the ones already in the sheet.
- You identify an event through its `location`, `title` and `description`.

#### Solution:

If all this is correct, then you can do the following:

- After retrieving the events from the calendar, use [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to retrieve the event details.
- If there are any old events in the sheet, filter them out of your `eventDetails` array, using [filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and [every()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every#:%7E:text=Description,every%20method%20immediately%20returns%20false%20.) (the second parameter of [slice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) is exclusive so, if you want to compare the three first properties, it should be `slice(0,3)` instead of `slice(0,2)`).
- If the filtered array of `eventDetails` is not empty (that is, there are new events in the Calendar), write those new events to your sheet.

#### Code sample:

```
function importCalendar(){ 
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Sheet1'); //Target sheet for events
  var calendarName = sheet.getRange('C2').getValue(); //name of calendar ex. calendar@gmailcom
  var start = sheet.getRange('C3').getValue(); //to date
  var end = sheet.getRange('C4').getValue();  //from date  
  var calendar = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(calendarName);
  if(!calendar) calendar = CalendarApp.getCalendarsByName(calendarName)[0];  
  var events = calendar.getEvents(start, end);
  var eventDetails = events.map(event => [event.getLocation(), event.getTitle(), event.getDescription(), event.getStartTime()]);
  var lastRow =  sheet.getLastRow();
  var startCol = 2; // Column where the event list starts
  var oldStartRow = 8; // Row where the event list starts
  var numCols = 4; // Number of event fields
  var numRows = lastRow - oldStartRow + 1;
  if (numRows !== 0) { // If there are events in the sheet, filter the duplicates
    var oldEvents = sheet.getRange(oldStartRow, startCol, lastRow - oldStartRow + 1, numCols).getValues();
    // Filter out duplicates:
    eventDetails = eventDetails.filter(eventRow => oldEvents.every(oldEvent => oldEvent.slice(0,3).join() != eventRow.slice(0,3).join()));    
  }
  if (eventDetails.length != 0) { // Check if there is any new event coming from the Calendar
    sheet.getRange(lastRow + 1, startCol, eventDetails.length, eventDetails[0].length).setValues(eventDetails);
  }
}
```